# Python web scraping header

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to do a web scraping with yahoo finance.
"https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AUDUSD%3DX/history?p=AUDUSD%3DX"

I finish the code and it returns the response code 404.
I notice that I need to add the user-agent header before I can scrape the website e.g.

```
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36",
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
}
```

But I was just wondering how can I get the above header information via python. Any code I should enter to get the  user-agent header? Thank you.

Comment: Header is there for the target website to tell which device and browser you're using, but you can freely input whatever string you want in the data. For example, the above example should work fine for scraping. Otherwise, it depends on which scraping implementation you're using.

Comment: If you want to get finance info it's just better to find an API for that. Good luck!

Comment: There isn't any python code to get you a user agent because user agents and browser/OS specific and are generated by the browser.  The one you are using is perfectly fine though so there is no need to look for others.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you check this package, maybe you might find it easier and less confusing:

[Download market data from Yahoo! Finance's API Python](https://pypi.org/project/yfinance/)